Static Files Not Loading in Production in Django-React application
I'm running a Django application in a Docker container, and I'm having trouble serving static files in production. Everything works fine locally, but when I deploy to production, the static files don't load, and I get 404 errors.
Here are the relevant parts of my setup:
Django settings.py:
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/vol/web/static'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build', 'static')]

The build folder was generated by npm run build command in a react application.
After running collectstatic, the volume /vol/web/static is correctly populated. However, the browser shows 404 errors for the static files, e.g.,
GET https://site/static/js/main.db771bdd.js [HTTP/2 404 161ms]
GET https://site/static/css/main.4b763604.css [HTTP/2 404 160ms]

Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://mysite/static/js/main.db771bdd.js”.

These files exist in the build/static directory, but I thought the browser should use the static files collected into /vol/web/static.
Nginx Configuration:
server {
    listen ${LISTEN_PORT};

    location /static {
        alias /vol/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass              ${APP_HOST}:${APP_PORT};
        include                 /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        client_max_body_size    10M;
    }
}

Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.9-alpine

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PATH="/scripts:${PATH}"

RUN pip install --upgrade "pip<24.1"

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client jpeg-dev \
    && apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp-build-deps \
       gcc libc-dev linux-headers postgresql-dev musl-dev zlib zlib-dev libffi-dev \
    && pip install -r /requirements.txt \
    && apk del .tmp-build-deps

RUN mkdir -p /app /vol/web/media /vol/web/static
RUN adduser -D user
RUN chown -R user:user /vol /app

COPY ./app /app
COPY ./scripts /scripts
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt

RUN chmod -R 755 /vol/web /app /scripts \
    && chmod +x /scripts/*

USER user
WORKDIR /app

VOLUME /vol/web

CMD ["entrypoint.sh"]

For further context, I deployed the Django application and the proxy in separated containers inside a ECS task:
[
    {
        "name": "api",
        "image": "${app_image}",
        "essential": true,
        "memoryReservation": 256,
        "environment": [
            {"name": "DJANGO_SECRET_KEY", "value": "${django_secret_key}"},
            {"name": "DB_HOST", "value": "${db_host}"},
            {"name": "DB_NAME", "value": "${db_name}"},
            {"name": "DB_USER", "value": "${db_user}"},
            {"name": "DB_PASS", "value": "${db_pass}"},
            {"name": "ALLOWED_HOSTS", "value": "${allowed_hosts}"},
            {"name": "S3_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME", "value": "${s3_storage_bucket_name}"},
            {"name": "S3_STORAGE_BUCKET_REGION", "value": "${s3_storage_bucket_region}"}
        ],
        "logConfiguration": {
            "logDriver": "awslogs",
            "options": {
                "awslogs-group": "${log_group_name}",
                "awslogs-region": "${log_group_region}",
                "awslogs-stream-prefix": "api"
            }
        },
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": 9000,
                "hostPort": 9000
            }
        ],
        "mountPoints": [
            {
                "readOnly": false,
                "containerPath": "/vol/web",
                "sourceVolume": "static"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "proxy",
        "image": "${proxy_image}",
        "essential": true,
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": 8000,
                "hostPort": 8000
            }
        ],
        "memoryReservation": 256,
        "environment": [
            {"name": "APP_HOST", "value": "127.0.0.1"},
            {"name": "APP_PORT", "value": "9000"},
            {"name": "LISTEN_PORT", "value": "8000"}
        ],
        "logConfiguration": {
            "logDriver": "awslogs",
            "options": {
                "awslogs-group": "${log_group_name}",
                "awslogs-region": "${log_group_region}",
                "awslogs-stream-prefix": "proxy"
            }
        },
        "mountPoints": [
            {
                "readOnly": true,
                "containerPath": "/vol/static",
                "sourceVolume": "static"
            }
        ]
    }
]

The entrypoint.sh script called by the Dockerfile is given by
#!/bin/sh

set -e
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput --settings=app.settings.staging
python manage.py wait_for_db --settings=app.settings.staging
python manage.py wait_for_es --settings=app.settings.staging
python manage.py migrate --settings=app.settings.staging
python manage.py search_index --rebuild --settings=app.settings.staging -f
uwsgi --socket :9000 --workers 4 --master --enable-threads --module app.wsgi --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings.staging

In terraform, my code is essentially equal to the configuration found here
I suspect there might be an issue with file permissions, but after I change the permission the errors continue. Any insights on what might be going wrong or how to debug this further?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The VOLUME declaration at the end of the Dockerfile is potentially problematic, I could see this causing the container to not see changes in the image's /vol/web/static directory.  Does deleting this help?  When you run the container, are you mounting something over that directory that would hide its contents?

I delete the VOLUME declaration and now I got the erro PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/vol/web/static' when running the entrypoint. I added more info regarding deployment details to further context.

I think the error lies in your nginx config.  You are setting the alias for the static route to /vol/static, instead of /vol/web/static:
server {
    listen ${LISTEN_PORT};

    location /static {
        alias /vol/web/static;
    }
    ...
}


Try to declare volumes in ECS task definition
"volumes": [
    {
        "name": "static",
        "host": {}
    }
],

Customize it depending on your setup.
Volumes on AWS documentation

But the volume is already declared in the terraform code I showed above. Should I declare the volume again in the container definitions?
